# I want to see user last name displayed after login my DAO ,Controller servlet and JSP code below always showing null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is my servlet
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

```
    try {PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
        boolean loggedin = false;
        Admin admin = new Admin();
        admin.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
        admin.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        admin.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
        
        AdminDao obj= new AdminDao();
        loggedin = obj.loginAdmin(admin);
        
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
        if (loggedin){
            
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("currentSessionAdmin", admin);
            
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("Admin_Election.jsp");
            
            
        }else{
            request.setAttribute("status", "failed");
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("Admin_Login.jsp");
        }
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(adminlogin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(adminlogin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    
}
```

}

```
    <br>`
```

Comment: `if (loggedin){` is probably false.  Make sure that your `admin` object is properly populated

Comment: Can you help me with how it should be done?

Comment: @ScaryWombat can you assist me here?

Comment: print out the values or step through using a debugger (these are essential skills) Make sure that the values do not have white space on the end.  What happens if you use hard coded values? Are you sure that that this user is in the DB? etc etc etc.

Comment: Yeah the user exists and it logs in successfully but name not displaying

Comment: Looking at your code, I can not see where you are setting the value in the session/request.  Also you do not show the relevant portion of the jsp.

Comment: @ScaryWombat                         <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            
                <%Admin admin = (Admin)session.getAttribute("currentSessionAdmin");%> 
            <%= admin.getLastName()%>
                

                    
        
        <br>

Comment: `admin = (Admin)session.getAttribute("currentSessionAdmin");` is OK, but where in your java code do you set this attribute?

Comment: In fact you are setting this attribute using a boolean value, You need to use the `admin` object

Comment: I have made changes in my servlet but still getting null
if (loggedin){
            
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("currentSessionAdmin", admin);
            
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("Admin_Election.jsp");
            
            
        }else{
            request.setAttribute("status", "failed");
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("Admin_Login.jsp");
        }
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

Comment: Please edit your question with all the code that you have put into comments.  Also if you are using JSTL you should not need to use the `<%` scriplets

Comment: Also, I think you should try to `redirect` not `forward`

Comment: Changes have been made to the code but still null

Comment: Tried response.sendRedirect

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what is wrong with your code.  All I can suggest from here is to create a really simple test.  In your servlet just have an admin object, hard code the value, set the session and then call the jsp.  In the jsp just print the value.  Get rid of all other code.  Get that working.

Answer (score -1):

you should call the object sent with [EL expression](https://jean-luc-massat.pedaweb.univ-amu.fr/ens/jee/tp-jsp2.html) `${}` in your `Admin_Election.jsp` `${currentSessionAdmin.lastName}`.   Hope that helps :)